# Enfocar EditText al iniciar la aplicación Android Studio con Java

Tags: java, android-studio, edittext

Estoy trabajando con Java en Android studio, quiero que se enfoque un EditText al iniciar la aplicación, probé de varias maneras pero no se enfoca y no toma los cambios.

Ocupe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al abrir la aplicación no lo selecciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: EditText miEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.miEditText);
    miEditText.requestFocus();

Asegúrate de reemplazar "miEditText" y "R.id.miEditText" con el nombre y el ID de tu EditText respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, con el código agregado puede resolver mi duda y aplicarlo a mi aplicación.

Excelente aportación.